# What is an electro-optic switch?

Tags: experimental-realization, photonics, optical-quantum-computing, quantum-optics

I found an implementation of a CNOT in photonic QC and I just couldn't find any info on a component named "electro-optic switch"

1. What does it do exactly?
2. How does it work?

The implementation in question is this: https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0607185

Comment: Do you have a link to where you found that implementation?

Comment: Yes, I was planning to but was in a hurry and forgot it, now it should be updated.